# How to pronounce route

Tags: pronunciation

How do u know when the "ou" in route is pronounced as "oo" or "ow"? Or does it just depend on the person who says it

Comment: I'm marking this as a exact dup too. However, I'd encourage readers to go answer that question, as IMHO this is an issue of dialect, and none of the answers currently over there (**particularly** the accepted one), really have that right.

Comment: I generally pronounce the verb one way and the noun the other way.  (And I switch on alternate days, just to keep it interesting.)

Comment: I don't recommend that Question's answers. The fact is that there are a lot of different pronunciations of _route_, especially in America. /rut/ and /rawt/ are both common, and people don't always care or even distinguish. The answers there give a lot of approximate spellings, which is more confusing than helpful, and they support the silly presupposition that there is only one "correct" pronunciation.

Answer (score 0):

In American English both route rhyming with shout and route rhyming with boot are acceptable, however in British English only route rhyming with boot is used, as rout is already an exiting British word with that pronunciation.

EDIT: John has informed me that rout is also an American English word as well, however the pronunciations stay the same.

Comment: _Rout_ is an accepted word in the US, too. But that doesn't bother us any.